# Entity Framework Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

Hello everyone I'm struggling with the migration of EntityFramework, for now, I have enabled automatic ones.

My software is wpf- mvvm-ef code first SQL-server

But I wanted to know how to handle a particular situation.

I do I install my software in all four machines read the db on a server.

I now you're releasing an update of my application (in this update has changed the structure of the db) and this update will only do two machines via

```
Database.SetInitializer (new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion <SednaContext, Configuration> ());
```

Him I automatically update the structure of db.

But now if I run my software from the other two machines that were not updated him I automatically returns the structure of db (returning to the old one because in these two machines I have not installed the update)

How can I avoid doing all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN post](/msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) said how to do db migration.

First, run the `Enable-Migrations` command in `Package Manager Console`. It will add a `Migrations` folder on your project, as the following picture.

[image: DB migration]

Note: In the `Package Manager Console`, the `Default project` should be the project which contains those model classes.

```
 public Configuration()
 {
      AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
 }
```

If you set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to be `true`, then you don't need to execute `Add-Migration` in `Package Manager Console` when a new db migration comes. It will do upgrade automatically. But I set it to be `false` by default. So every time I modified my models, I need to execute `Add-Migration`, and it will generate a class in the `Migrations` folder. The class has 2 functions, `Up()` and `Down()`. `Up()` contains codes about upgrading database to the version, and `Down()` describes how to downgrade the new one to the older version.

Hope these information could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply,
I had already tried this method, I have tried both automatic and manual.

My problem is another, entity framework how recognizing that needs to update the db most recently?

If I have installed my software in 4 pc.
But I upgrade only two pc at the beginning (so I update the schema of the db).
The other two are off.
If then after a few days, I turn the other two PCs (those not upgraded) and I do not update them, just run the software detects a change in the db and it return the old schema of db.

For this I am trying to understand how to catch what version of db schema is updating.

I hope to be more clear.

Comment: Try this post to understand how migrations work http://codingcanvas.com/entity-framework-code-first-migrations/